# How to populate multiselect picklist from list or array of string or a string(; separated) in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, multi-select

In my lightning web component, I have a  which has a multiselect picklist field from an object. I want to populate that field with values from a list returned from an apex method. I tried to assign the result (which is a list of strings) to the variable in LWC. Though I can see the values in console.log, I am not able to see it in the .

HTML:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name={objectName}>

<!-- This is the custom multiselect picklist field -->
<!-- Doesnt show selected options as English;English123-->
<lightning-input-field field-name = "Languages__c" value={languagesVar}></lightning-input-field>

<!-- Also tried to use dual-listbox but it didnt work either-->
<lightning-dual-listbox name="Languages"
                            label="Languages"
                            source-label="Available"
                            selected-label="Chosen"  
                            value={languagesVar}
                            onchange={handleChange} ></lightning-dual-listbox>

</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS:

```
import getLanguagesMethod from '@salesforce/apex/LanguageController.getLanguagesMethod';
@api languagesVar;

get languagesVar(){
        let returnLangs;
       
        getLanguagesMethod({ recordId: this.recordId })
                .then(result => {
                   returnLangs = result;
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(returnLangs)); //Output: "English;English123"
                   console.log(returnLangs);//Output: English;English123
                })                 
        }
        
        return returnLangs;
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getLanguagesMethod(Id recordId) {
        Contact con = [Select Languages__c from contact where Id = :recordId limit 1];
        return con.Languages__c; {English;English123}
}
```

How do I assign value to languagesVar in JS to show 'Selected' values of the multiselect picklist in LWC as 'English' and 'English123' which is returned from a string (that is ; separated) or from a List returned from Apex.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using this by the way - note it also uses an `options` array https://github.com/rapsacnz/MultiSelect

Answer (score 1):

A [required attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/specification), `options`, is missing from your lightning-dual-listbox.
It must be an array of object with two attributes: `value` and `label`. I.E.:

```js
options = [
    { value: 'English', label: 'English' },
    { value: 'English123', label: 'English 123' },
    { value: 'French', label: 'French' },
    { value: 'Spanish', label: 'Spanish' }
];
```

Then `value` attribute must be an array, not a string, and the array must hold a subset of values included in `options`. I.E.:

```js
values = [
    'English',
    'English123'
];
```

You can call [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on your string to divide it into an array of substring.

So your controller could be:

```js
@api selectedLanguages = [];
wiredLanguages; // in order to call refreshApex(this.wiredLanguages);

options = [
    { value: 'English', label: 'English' },
    { value: 'English123', label: 'English 123' },
    { value: 'French', label: 'French' },
    { value: 'Spanish', label: 'Spanish' }
];

@wire(getLanguagesMethod, { recordId: '$recordId'})
getLanguages(result) {
    this.wiredLanguages = result;
    if (result.data) {
        this.selectedLanguages = result.data.split(';');
    } else if (result.error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong while retrieving languages:', result.error);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-dual-listbox
    name="Languages"
    label="Languages"
    source-label="Available"
    selected-label="Chosen"  
    options={options}
    value={selectedLanguages}
    onchange={handleChange} >
</lightning-dual-listbox>
```

Be sure to take a look at [the reference page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/documentation).
By the way, the apex method could be cacheable.